# How to cause an automatic system restore by Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I want to cause a System Restore by Windows 7 during the next boot, how can i do? I may corrupt/delete a system file, but which one?

Comment: Boot to the Windows Recovery Environment ( WinRE ) simplest method of doing that is booting to a Windows 7 installation disk.

Comment: You can run system restore while in windows, open a run box (Win key + R key), type in rstrui.exe   , hit ok, Pick a restore date and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend [rollback rx home edition](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=40#Features). It's freeware and basically allows you to restore a PC to a point you make. Helpful if you accidentally delete a system file or get a virus. I use the paid version but the free home edition works very well!